# Having the name of files in a list, Select, copy and paste files from current directory to specific directory

Tags: python

Using Python, I have a list of 7000 elements. Each element is the name of one document I have in directory with  40.000 files.

I would like to select the files that I have in my list, copy and paste each file into another specific directory.

The problem is that the name of my files in the list look like that:

```
['GCA_002774085.1',
 'GCA_002774085.1',
 'GCA_002774085.1',
 'GCA_002774085.1',
 'GCA_002774285.1',
 'GCA_002774285.1',
 'GCA_002774285.1',
... ]
```

And the real names of my files look like this:

And in my directory, I have a massive number of files.

[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIDg3.png)

Using Python, which would be the best approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first add the "_genomic.fna.gz" to everything in your list so the file list matches the filenames in the folder

```
new_list=[item+"_genomic.fna.gz" for item in old_list]
```

Then using the `os` and `shutil` modules we can go through the directory and copy everything in the list

```
import os, shutil
folderpath="Path/to/your/folder"
for file in os.listdir(folderpath):
    if file in new_list:
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(folderpath,file),os.path.join(NEW_FOLDER,file))
```

Comment: Dear KJTH, many thanks again for your help. I code worked however for a reason I can't explain, some files (with exactly the same name) were not selected.

I have asked this problem in this question. Here, I let you know the link in case you would like to comment.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549846/problem-selecting-files-from-directory-with-name-recorded-in-a-list